# VBA: Formatting Multiple Selected Charts

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am looking to format multiple **selected** charts on Excel 2010 using VBA. The code below works when only one chart is selected but when multiple charts are selected, I get a "run-time error '91' Object variable or With Block variable not set". Any idea how to run the macro for number of **selected** charts?

```
Sub ChartFormat5_Click()


''Adjust chart area

'Size
Selection.Width = 631.9
Selection.Height = 290.1

'Border
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
    .Weight = 1
    .DashStyle = msoLineSolid
End With

'Font
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 10
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
End With


End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will process the active chart or all selected charts. The first routine determines what to process (active chart or selected charts) and the second processes each.

```
Sub FormatCharts()
  Dim obj As Object

  If Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    FormatOneChart ActiveChart
  Else
    For Each obj In Selection
      If TypeName(obj) = "ChartObject" Then
        FormatOneChart obj.Chart
      End If
    Next
  End If
End Sub

Sub FormatOneChart(cht As Chart)
  ' do all your formatting here, based on cht not on ActiveChart
End Sub
```

Don't select parts of the chart, just fully reference them. Instead of

```
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
With Selection.Format.Line
```

use this

```
With cht.ChartArea.Format.Line
```

etc.

Note: this is a duplicate of [VBA: Formatting Multiple Selected Charts (Chart, Plot, Legend, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087497/vba-formatting-multiple-selected-charts-chart-plot-legend-etc/)

Answer (score 1):

After some trial-n-error, I figured out how to make it work if you have just one or multiple charts selected. It was straightforward, but this worked when I tested it.

Note that I broke the actual Chart Area formatting into a separate sub.

```
Sub ChartFormat5_Click()

    Select Case TypeName(Selection)

        Case Is = "ChartArea" `only 1 selected

            FormatChart Selection

        Case Is = "DrawingObjects" 'more than 1 selected

            Dim cht As ChartObject
            For Each cht In Selection
                FormatChart cht.Chart.ChartArea
            Next

    End Select

End Sub

Sub FormatChart(chtArea As ChartArea)

With chtArea

    'size
    .Width = 631.9
    .Height = 290.1

    With .Format
        'Border
        With .Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
            .Transparency = 0
            .Weight = 1
            .DashStyle = msoLineSolid
        End With

        'Font
        With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 10
            With .Fill
                .Visible = msoTrue
                With .ForeColor
                    .ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Brightness = 0
                End With
                .Transparency = 0
                .Solid
            End With
        End With
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Scott - this works great! However, now I'm having trouble if I'm only trying to run the macros for one selected graph (i.e. 1 out of 5 graphs)... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JKo_FinanceUse - did you see my comment in the code about `'change ws.ChartObjects to "Selection`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1569536/scott-holtzman - yup so I replaced the ws.ChartObjects with Selection but when I attempt to run a single selected chart, I get a run-time error '438' object doesn't support this property or method. Actually, the line I get the error msg is at "For Each cht In Selection".

Comment: @JKo_FinanceUse - see my edited answer. It was as bit trickier then I would have suspected, and it may be a bit of a hack, but it worked when I tested both conditions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1569536/scott-holtzman one more question Scott. Let's say I want to format the plot area, axis, legend, etc. as well. How would I adjust the code above to execute this? Please check revised code above. Thanks.

Comment: @JKo_FinanceUse - since this is a separate question, please post a new question to SO if you are still having trouble. Also, please revert your code back to the original question, otherwise its' going to be very confusing for people who land on this question in the future to understand the original problem and how this answer helped solve it.

Comment: Done - I'll post a new question now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hy try:

```
Sub ChartFormat5_Click_v02()

  For i = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count

    Application.Sheets(i).Activate

    For j = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count

        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(j).Activate


        'your code here

    Next j

  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Andre - it looks like it is only selecting the last chart in the sheet... I would like to automate formatting for ONLY those that I select

Comment: Actually, this script format all charts in all sheets. If you like to format just ONLY chart selected, the Answer of @Scott Holtzman is the better option.