# VBA: Formatting Multiple Selected Charts (Chart, Plot, Legend, etc.)

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am looking to format multiple selected charts on Excel 2010 using VBA. I want the code to work whether I choose one or multiple charts. The code below works when only one chart is selected but when multiple charts are selected, I get a "run-time error '91' Object variable or With Block variable not set". Any idea how to run the macro for number of selected charts?

```
Sub ChartFormat5_Click()


''Adjust chart area
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

'Size
Selection.Width = 631.9
Selection.Height = 290.1

'Border
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
    .Weight = 1
    .DashStyle = msoLineSolid
End With

'Font
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 10
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
End With


''Adjust axis alignment and format

ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
End With
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 1
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = 45

ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0_);(#,##0)"
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
End With

ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Select
Selection.Left = 1.5
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse


''Adjust legend box

ActiveChart.Legend.Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
    .Transparency = 0
End With
Selection.Left = 124
Selection.Top = 67

''Adjust plot area size and format
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select

'Borders
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
    .Weight = 0.75
    .DashStyle = msoLineSolid
End With

'Size
Selection.Width = ActiveChart.ChartArea.Width - 30.4
Selection.Height = ActiveChart.ChartArea.Height - 8.5
Selection.Top = 4
Selection.Left = 20

'Gridlines
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
End With
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .DashStyle = msoLineDash
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1569536/scott-holtzman - hey Scott, here's the new code/question. Thanks!

Comment: it will help if you post the code you have from the previous answer and how you need to add in the plot, axes, legend, etc. The way you wrote the question is like you never got a previous answer at all, and are asking the community to start from scratch. By the way, one answer to this is to incorporate separate subs for each `object` you are working with. So, one sub for plot, one for axes, one for legend, then pass that object into the sub. The same way I did for the chart area in the previous answer. See if you can work this out and get to me (or SO) if you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will process the active chart or all selected charts. The first routine determines what to process (active chart or selected charts) and the second processes each.

```
Sub FormatCharts()
  Dim obj As Object

  If Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    FormatOneChart ActiveChart
  Else
    For Each obj In Selection
      If TypeName(obj) = "ChartObject" Then
        FormatOneChart obj.Chart
      End If
    Next
  End If
End Sub

Sub FormatOneChart(cht As Chart)
  ' do all your formatting here, based on cht not on ActiveChart
End Sub
```

Don't select parts of the chart, just fully reference them. Instead of

```
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
With Selection.Format.Line
```

use this

```
With cht.ChartArea.Format.Line
```

etc.

Comment: Jon - this worked perfectly. This was really easy to adopt and implement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just started answering questions on stackoverflow, so I hope this will help you out.

Since you selected multiple charts at once, you should scrap `ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select` 
Just loop through each ChartObject in your current selection as follows:

```
Sub ChartFormat5_Click()
Dim cObject As ChartObject
For Each cObject In Selection
    With cObject
    'Do all your stuff here... E.g.
        .Chart.PlotArea.Width = 631.9
    End With
Next cObject
End Sub
```

Comment: If only one chart is selected, then `Selection` will not be the chart object, it will be whatever chart element was clicked on, so it will not process the active chart. This is why I broke the code into two parts in my answer.

Comment: That also explains why you went looping through all the objects in the selection, instead of only all ChartObjects. Indeed a better scenario, since it keeps unexpected user input into account. Have an upvote :)